# Há algum correspondente em português dos dynamic verbs e stative verbs em inglês?

Tags: verbos

O ThoughtCo. diz o seguinte sobre esses tipos de verbos:

> What's the Difference Between a Dynamic Verb and a Stative Verb?
>
> A dynamic verb (such as run, ride, grow, throw) is primarily used to indicate an action, process, or sensation. In contrast, a stative verb (such as be, have, seem, know) is primarily used to describe a state or situation. (Because the boundary between dynamic and stative verbs can be fuzzy, it's generally more useful to talk of dynamic and stative meaning and usage.)
>
> Nordquist, Richard. "Definition and Examples of Dynamic Verbs." ThoughtCo, Aug. 27, 2020, thoughtco.com/what-is-a-dynamic-verb-1690487.

Eu tenho a sensação de que *stative verbs* são os verbos de ligação em português, e os *dynamic verbs* são os verbos transitivos e intransitivos. Está correcta esta percepção? Se não, há alguma correspondência em português para esses conceitos?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Há correspondente: **verbos estativos** ou **de estado** e **verbos eventivos**. Para definições concisas vê [Afrânio da Silva Garcia, *Verbos Incompatíveis com o Progressivo — Estudo Comparativo do Inglês e do Português*, UERJ, 2010 (p. 157)](https://www.e-publicacoes.uerj.br/index.php/soletras/article/view/5171/3794):

> Assim sendo, **os verbos podem ser divididos em dois tipos em relação ao caráter: *eventivos* e *estativos***.
>
> ***Eventivos***, do sentido mais amplo da palavra evento: *acontecimento, ocorrência*, indica um verbo que traduz a *ocorrência de uma modificação qualquer*, seja no sujeito, seja no objeto. Mesmo a *modificação* de um estado para outro, como nos verbos incoativos
> (envelhecer etc.), caracteriza um verbo como *eventivo*.
>
> ***Estativos***, derivado de estado, indica um verbo denotativo de uma situação em que *não ocorre qualquer modificação* quer no sujeito, quer no objeto.

E este artigo de [Carlos Rocha no Ciberdúvidas (2006)](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/saber-e-conhecer-como-verbos-estativos/18104) faz uma pequena apresentação dos verbos estativos (formatação minha):

> Um **verbo estativo** descreve um estado, ou seja, uma situação não dinâmica. Segundo Maria Helena Mira Mateus et aliae (*Gramática da Língua Portuguesa*, Lisboa, Editorial Caminho, 2003, pág. 191), a classe dos **verbos estativos têm várias subclasses**, entre elas, os verbos **existenciais** (*haver, ser, existir*), os verbos **locativos** (morar, ter, pertencer), os verbos **epistémicos** (*saber*), os verbos **perceptivos** (*ver*), os verbos **psicológicos** como *gostar* e os verbos **copulativos** (*ser* em «ser professor» e *andar* em «andar triste»).

Portanto os **verbos de ligação**, ou **copulativos**, são estativos, mas muitos verbos estativos não são copulativos. E quer estativos quer eventivos podem ser transitivos ou intransitivos:

**Exemplos de verbos estativos:**

> Intransitivos: A mula sem cabeça **existe** e **mora** em Almada
>
> Transitivo direto: **Adoro** café e **detesto** tabaco
>
> Transitivo indireto: **Gosto** de café

**Exemplos de verbos eventivos:**

> Intransitivos: Ela **espirrou** e **sorriu**
>
> Transitivo direto: **Descascou** a maçã e **comeu**-a
>
> Transitivo indireto: Já **telefonei** ao João